# $f*\rho_\epsilon \to f$ pointwise convergence of convolution (approximate identity)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

A sequence of functions $\rho_\epsilon \in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$ ) is called an approximate identity if $\rho_\epsilon \ge0$ , $\int \rho_\epsilon(x)dx=1$ and $\int_{|x|>\delta} \rho_\epsilon(x)dx \to 0 , \forall \delta>0$ as $\epsilon\to0$.

prove that if $f$ is continuous and bounded then 
$$f*\rho_\epsilon \to f , \text{pointwise}$$

I guess I can show that $\|f*\rho_\epsilon -f\|_1\to 0$. but how do I show the pointwise convergence here? (once I look at it I cannot see a way to bring the function $f$ itself out of the intergral)

Comment: Any L1 convergent sequence has a pointwise convergent subsequence. Therefore $f*\rho_{\epsilon}(x)$ has a subsequence converging to f(x). What remains to show is that $f*\rho_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a convergent sequence for all x.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$. Then $|\int f(x-y)\rho_{\epsilon} (y) dy -f(x)|\leq \int |f(x-y)-f(x)|\rho_{\epsilon} (y) dy$. Now $\int |f(x-y)-f(x)|\rho_{\epsilon} (y) dy =\int_{|y| <\delta} |f(x-y)-f(x)|\rho_{\epsilon} (y) dy+\int_{|y| \geq \delta} |f(x-y)-f(x)|\rho_{\epsilon} (y) dy$

Given $\eta >0$ choose $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x-y)-f(x)| <\eta$ for  $|y|<\delta$. Then use boundedness of $f$ and the fact that $\int_{|y| \geq \delta} \rho_{\epsilon} (y) dy \to 0$ to make the second term $<\eta$ for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

Comment: but here you're showing $\|f*\rho_\epsilon-f\|\to 0$, right?

Comment: @stat_yale No, I am fixing $x$ and showing that convergence at $x$ holds.